# swift hiding navigationbar and adding a custom back button not sure if I am doing it right

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

My root VC contains a navbar. What I want to do is to hide the navbar in the second view and implement my own back button.

What I have done so far:

In storyboard in the simulated metrics section for VC2 I have set **"Top bar"  = none**

This hides the navigationbar in storyboard for that VC. Then I have made a uiview with a height of 20 and a top constraint of -20 in order to give my statusbar the same background color as the rootVC.

Then for the back button I have made a button with a function that fires

```
navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

So is this the proper way to hide the navigation bar for the second VC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simulated metrics are just that - simulated. They have no effect on the application.
In the second VC viewDidLoad put

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
```

Comment: Should I put it in viewdidload or apppear?

Comment: Normally you need to do it only once.

Comment: In second vc I have set self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true) in viewdidload
And then when the back button gets clicked I fire:
navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
        
        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false

Looks like it works, so should I do it this way then?